# How to make an element's height increase with every child added to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, positioning

I have a `<div>` that has children appended to it by a script.  These children elements are automatically appended by a PHP script and positioned using `position:absolute`.  I tried to give the parent `<div>` the style `min-height:400px` allowing the elements appended to the `<div>` to increase the parent's height.  The only problem is that the height does not increase when I do this.  Does anybody know what I can do to fix this?

**EDIT:** I am not able to use `position:relative` for positioning my elements.  Are there any solutions that allow for `position:absolute`.

Comment: Try `position: relative;` instead because absolute positioned elements are no longer in the document flow so the parent div doesn't care about them. But you should post the relevant code.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to use position: absolute? The container will naturally expand with new content *unless* you use position: absolute, so it seems you are shooting yourself in the foot here unnecessarily ... unless there's something we haven't been told.

Comment: @ralph.m there's something we'll never know... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes you can use position absolute** (yeee♥!)

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO TEST CASE](http://jsbin.com/etawil/3/edit)**</kbd>

By simply doing:

```
$(this).height( this.scrollHeight );
```

or with pure JS:

```
this.style.height = this.scrollHeight ;
```

and adding this to your element's CSS:

```
overflow:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
```

**Edit:**

The [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wvDkn/1/) tested fine in IE10, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera.

The key point here is setting the overflow value for the x or y axis (whichever dimensions you need the size of) to `auto`, rather than the default value of `visible`. Then the `scrollWidth` or `scrollHeight` property can be used on the HTML DOM object to get the full size of the element, including any absolutely-positioned descendants.

Odd as it seems, this is entirely consistent with the fact that setting `overflow:hidden` for a container clips any absolutely-positioned descendants. Apparently, elements with `position:absolute` aren't quite as "out of the flow" as we've always been told :)

Comment: +1 Nice trick! The [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/wvDkn/1/) tested fine in IE10, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera. It looks like the key point is setting the overflow value for the x or y axis (whichever dimensions you need the size of) to `auto`, rather than the default value of `visible`. Odd as it seems, this is entirely consistent with the fact that setting `overflow:hidden` for a container clips any absolutely-positioned descendants. Apparently, elements with `position:absolute` aren't quite as "out of the flow" as we've always been told :)

Comment: @MattCoughlin may you please copy this text from your comment and add it to my answer? **☻** thanks

Comment: @roXon: Done! Optionally, the answer could be turned into a community wiki if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `position: absolute` for this because stuff that is positioned that way will be pulled out of the normal render flow. This results in the parent not noticing that its content  s acually very high. Use `position: relative` for the child div's. This way the parent will grow automatically.